# problem with query for phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to sql/phpmyadmin and am having problems with this query.

```
SELECT `2.checkNumber`,`1.customerName'
FROM 
`classicmodels1` AS 1,
`classicmodels2` AS 2
WHERE `1.customerNumber`=`2.customerNumber`
```

Comment: You should add what kind of problems. Although in this case, I'm fairly sure it's the numeric table aliases. Try `t1` instead of `1`

Comment: I am still getting an error which says "#1046 - No database selected". Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
`1.customerName'
```

with

```
`1.customerName`
```

Or even better rewrite it to avoid using quotes. Also I would replace aliases '1' and '2' with 't1' and 't2' respectively:

```
SELECT t2.checkNumber,t1.customerName
FROM 
classicmodels1 AS t1,
classicmodels2 AS t2
WHERE t1.customerNumber=t2.customerNumber
```

Comment: I am still getting an error which says "#1046 - No database selected". Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user you need to choose a database in phpMyAdmin before you can run the query. There should be a list on the left hand side

Comment: Hi, I am now getting this error #1146 - Table 'classicmodels2.classicmodels1' doesn't exist with this query SELECT `t2.payments.checkNumber`,`t1.customers.customerName`
FROM 
`classicmodels1` AS t1,
`classicmodels2` AS t2
WHERE `t1.customers.customerName`=`t2.payments.checkNumber`

Comment: @user, you should read something about SQL. `t2.payments.checkNumber` - this is invalid construction.